# Ubuntu and LAN games (specfically Minecraft)

Tags: wireless, minecraft

We both have Ubuntu 12.04, same Minecraft version, same network as each other via wireless.

It says scanning for LAN and it never shows up.

Does Ubuntu have a built-in firewall that blocks connections from the local area network, and if so is there anyway to change it?

Comment: Are you running a Minecraft server, or just using the "Open World to LAN" option?

Comment: I am using "Open to LAN".

Answer (score 5):

First, you should check the firewall configuration on the computer running the server (the one on which you opened your world to LAN).

*ufw* is the default firewall interface on Ubuntu (you will need a terminal).

```
> sudo ufw status verbose
```

Bellow is the configuration for one of my home server:

```
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
5901/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere
22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
5901/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

We can see that all incoming connections are denied, while all outgoing are allowed (this a standard configuration).
Additional rules allow incoming connections to SSH (22) and VNC (5901) ports.

If you are on a LAN, behind a router and the router doesn't forward ports to your computers, it should be safe to disable the firewall:

```
sudo ufw disable
```

An other option I would feel more comfortable with is to allow anything coming from your LAN:

```
sudo ufw allow in from 192.168.0.0/24
```

This assuming that is using addresses looking like this : 192.168.0.* 
You can check that using

```
ip addr show | grep "inet "
```

Mine is on IP 192.168.0.9 :

```
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
inet 192.168.0.9/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global wlan0
```

I don't really know how minecraft works, but it should only be necessary to change the firewall settings on the minecraft server.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Ubuntu should block incoming connections, but allow all outgoing connections.  If you're on a LAN, you shouldn't need the firewall, so you can read [this wiki page](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-firewall-on-off.html) for directions on how to disable it.

Once the firewall is disabled, you can then play to your heart's content.

Answer (score -1):

It probably is your router configuration. This happened with me a long time ago in Windows. Search in your router's manual about "How to open ports". Or search the internet. Just remember that the process can change depending on your model. The default Minecraft LAN Server port is 25565.

Comment: This only applies if you're connecting from a different network. It shouldn't matter if both players are on the same Wi-Fi.

Comment: Also, open to LAN uses a random port.